# Chome undesirably downloads PHP files

Tags: java, php, browser, webserver

When clicking a link on a webpage, Chrome downloads a PHP file. The content is some XML that's irrelevant to me. A rarity, I would rather Chrome behaved like IE in the same circumstance, which is to open a Java application.

Based on prior research of this topic, allow me to preempt possible answers:

1. I do not have Internet Download Manager.
2. I have already tried clearing ALL my cached data from the beginning of time.

By way of comparison, Firefox prompts me to save or open the file with Java Web Starter; choosing the latter results in desired behavior.

I've read something about installing Xamp or Wamp - I don't really understand what these are, and am reluctant to install these. In addition to learning what to do to mollify Chrome, I'd like to learn what Chrome is trying to do, and why it doesn't work when IE and Firefox are capable of doing so. In that regard a general explanation of php files, their relationship to Java and/or Java Web Starter is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as a programming question.

Comment: @BSMP I don't think stackoverflow is exclusively for programming questions. I see it well populated with "general techie" questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: While this looks more fit for [Super User](http://superuser.com), I'll give my two cents on this. I think this has something to do with [Chrome dropping NPAPI support as of last year](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).

Comment: @BSMP I stand corrected. Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: @Revenant The article at the link you sent sounds like a valid explanation for what I'm seeing. If you wanna post that as an answer, I'd flag it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While this looks more fit for Super User, I'll give my two cents on this. I think this has something to do with Chrome dropping NPAPI support as of last year.

To elaborate, Java browser plugins rely on the NPAPI, which Chrome dropped support for starting version 45. Oracle doesn't seem to work on how to fix this, instead they push users to seek alternatives that still support NPAPI (i.e. Firefox, Safari).

In that context, when Chrome loads the page in question, it acts like it doesn't have Java installed (as it doesn't have the means to open the Java application).

References/further reading:

- [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)
- [Java and Google Chrome Browser](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)
- [Will my Java Applets run on Chrome 45?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451274/will-my-java-applets-run-on-chrome-45)

Comment: As for why the page returns an XML file, I don't really know why, but I think it meant to do that if they knew you don't have Java or your browser is Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste this PHP and save it  as a php file called download.php. Then call it when you want to download the file with the name of the file. For example:

download.php?file=nameofyourfilehere

This will force the file to be downloaded rather than opened. It can also handle large file sizes.

```
<?php

$file = $_REQUEST['file'];
$filename = $file;

  define('CHUNK_SIZE', 1024*1024); // Size (in bytes) of tiles chunk

  // Read a file and display its content chunk by chunk
  function readfile_chunked($filename, $retbytes = TRUE) {
    $buffer = '';
    $cnt =0;
    // $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($handle === false) {
      return false;
    }
    while (!feof($handle)) {
      $buffer = fread($handle, CHUNK_SIZE);
      echo $buffer;
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      if ($retbytes) {
        $cnt += strlen($buffer);
      }
    }
    $status = fclose($handle);
    if ($retbytes && $status) {
      return $cnt; 
    }
    return $status;
  }


header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file).";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile_chunked($filename);
exit(); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually desired the opposite: i.e. I want Chrome to open the application, not download the php file. IE automatically opens the application, and Firefox prompts me to open the php file with Java Web Starter - either is a desired behavior, but downloading the php file is not.